# Fit a nonlinear model with python and gekko

Tags: python, gekko

I have a dataset of trees. In this dataset, I have the unique number of Plot, the sequence in the order when were take the data "Measurement" and the Height mean in meters and Age mean in years for the trees. Something like this:
[head of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLsAh.png)

next, I define the model to predict the Height using the Age in this way:

> Height = B0 * ((1 - exp(-B1 *Age))**B2)

My goal is to determinate the values of B0, B1 & B2 respectively. For this, I use the package gekko to find the parameters of the models with the next code:

```
num_p = data_gek.Plot.unique()
nmp = 5
number_p = (data_gek.Plot == num_p[nmp])

m = GEKKO()

xm = np.array(data_gek[number_p]['Age'])
x = m.Param(value=xm)

B0 = m.FV(value=38.2) #value=38.2
B0.STATUS = 1

B1 = m.FV(value=0.1) #value=0.1
B1.STATUS = 1

B2 = m.FV(value=2.08) #value=2.08
B2.STATUS = 1

ym =  np.array(data_gek[number_p]['Height'])
z = m.CV(value=ym)

y = m.Var()
m.Equation(y==B0 * ((1 - m.exp(-B1 *x))**B2))
m.Obj(((y-z)/z)**2)

m.options.IMODE = 2
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=False)

print(B0.value[0],B1.value[0],B2.value[0])
#output 
27.787958561 0.0052435491089 0.21178326158
```

However, I don't sure that I make in the right way. Is it possible to do this without initial values in parameters? Because I used previous values for B0, B1, and B2 from literature.

If you gonna see my dataset and my process you could access this [notebook in Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GH5zK6zSu3sliTm3GppA9i-K2DKy6C-b).

Answer (score 2):

Your script has just one problem. The definition of `z` needs to be a `Param` or `MV` type instead of a `CV` as `z = m.Param(value=ym)` because it is an input to your objective function.

You can also use the [built-in objective](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EstimatorObjective) if you define `y` as a `CV` instead of a `Var`. You just need to turn on the [feedback status](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionFstatus) `FSTATUS=1` to use an objective function that minimizes the difference between the measurements and model predictions. Here is a modified version of your script.

[image: regression fit]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
url = 'http://apmonitor.com/pdc/uploads/Main/data_2nd_order.txt'
data = pd.read_csv(url)
m  = GEKKO()
xm = np.array(data['time'])
x  = m.Param(value=xm)
B0 = m.FV(1); B1 = m.FV(1); B2 = m.FV(1)
B0.STATUS = 1; B1.STATUS = 1; B2.STATUS = 1
ym =  np.array(data['output (y)'])
y  = m.CV(value=ym)
y.FSTATUS = 1
yi = m.Intermediate(B0 * ((1 - m.exp(-B1 *x))**B2))
m.Equation(y==yi)
m.options.IMODE = 2
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=True)
print(B0.value[0],B1.value[0],B2.value[0])
plt.plot(xm,ym,'ro')
plt.plot(xm,y.value,'b--')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I try to use your code but it doesn't still work. I get `Exception:  @error: Solution Not Found`. Even I cleaning my data searching out layers and missing data. Could you take a look at [my data](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GH5zK6zSu3sliTm3GppA9i-K2DKy6C-b )? I think is more complicated than your example.

Comment: Try changing the initial values for ```B0```, ```B1``` , and ```B2``` from 1 to the initial values you found in the literature. ```B0 = m.FV(38.2)``` and so on...

Comment: Another thing to try is to set bounds on your parameters, especially `B1`. A large negative value will cause the term `m.exp()` to have a very large value and make it difficult for the solver to converge. You can add bounds with `B0 = m.FV(lb=0,ub=100)`. @reyPanda has a good suggestion as well to use better initial values. You can combine those suggestions with `B0 = m.FV(value=38.2,lb=0,ub=100)`